# ProgressBar is not updating from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm using ProgressBar to try and display the progress of downloading and saving a file. The ProgressBar shows up, but stays at 0, until it closes when the task is finished. I've tried different approaches, but it just won't update. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
class downloadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        int count; 
        try 
        {

            URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            File testDirectory = new File(MainActivity.this.getFilesDir(), "downloadedData.txt");
            if (!testDirectory.exists()) 
            {
                testDirectory.mkdir();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testDirectory+"/downloadedData.txt");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) 
            {
                total += count;

                int neki = (int)(((double)total/lenghtOfFile)*100);
                this.publishProgress(neki);

                fos.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("ERROR DOWNLOADING","Unable to download" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        super.publishProgress(values);
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**onCreate**

```
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setMax(100);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Data");
```

And when the button is clicked that starts the downloading: `progressDialog.show();`

Comment: Have you managed to solve this eventually?

Comment: No, I just used the spinning progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug where the progress is calculated. It might be a cast problem, you can try to do it in 2 steps to avoid getting 0 after your division. But again you should create a variable with this progress value, put a breakpoint there and see the casting problem !

Comment: It's throwing numbers in -100000 range.

Comment: It is -1 because it is not set in the header of what you are trying to download : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength() You need to find another way to get the size of what you are downloading

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem might be in your code, but you have have a go at this     **`progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(incrementValue);`**

Answer (score 0):

This may sound a bit tard but have you tried to `invalidate()` the ProgressBar after you set the progress? I am not sure it does one automatically when you set the progress.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and spent hours on it. The problem is in calculation of the progress value.

```
 int neki = (int)(((double)total/lenghtOfFile)*100);
```

Instead you should do calculation in two steps:

```
int neki = total * 100;
neki = (int)(neki/lengthOfFile);

publishProgress(neki);
```

This solved my problem. Hope this will help.